# What is the difference between auto hosted, provider hosted and sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012, apps-development

What actually happens when we create apps, and where are three types of apps hosted these apps hosted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following image can give you an overview of the entire app schema:

[image]

Following you can read the definition for each type of hosted app:

**Sharepoint hosted app**

> SharePoint-hosted apps, or apps where all components are hosted on either an on-premises or Office 365 SharePoint farm. SharePoint-hosted apps are installed on a SharePoint 2013 website, called the host web. They have their resources hosted on an isolated subsite of a host web, called the app web. It’s important to know the difference between host webs and app webs. Figure 1 illustrates the basic architecture of a SharePoint-hosted app.
>   [image]

**Provider hosted apps**

> Provider-hosted apps for SharePoint include components that are deployed and hosted outside the SharePoint farm. They are installed to the host web, but their remote components are hosted on another server. Figure 2 illustrates the basic architecture of a provider-hosted app.[image]

**Autohosted apps**

> Autohosted apps for SharePoint are cloud-hosted apps whose remote
>   components are provisioned and deployed for you on Windows Azure. As
>   with a provider-hosted app, an autohosted app for SharePoint can
>   interact with a SharePoint website but also uses resources and
>   services that are located on a remote site that is hosted by Windows
>   Azure. The SharePoint 2013 installation provisions and deploys these
>   resources for you.[image]

For more information, please: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Autohosted apps are deprecated since summer 14!